# How to store argument passed to %post script inside RPM file

Tags: rpm, rpmbuild

As mentioned here - http://meinit.nl/rpm-spec-prepostpreunpostun-argument-values

The argument passed to the `%post` script can be used to identify the mode of RPM installation.

I want to store this argument in value in one of the RPM file (install-mode.property)

How can I fetch the argument passed to `%post` script and store it inside `install-mode.property` file which is bundled in the same RPM

The final outcome should be RPM installation location has `install-mode.property` file containing the value `1/2` depending on whether the RPM was installed or upgraded.

Is there any token based replacement supported by RPM that can help me with storing this argument in the property file.

Anything that works would be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

You can write the post-install script in any language you want. The default is shell, so you can just do:

```
echo $1 > (path to your files)/install-mode.property
```

Note that your `rpm -V` will likely fail after, because the `install-mode.property` file on disk doesn't match what the RPM shipped with.